# Day of the week - Javascript

Tags: javascript, getdate

Something is really off about my script..

```
    //Day of the Week
    checkDate = "03/18/15";
    year = checkDate.substr(6,2);
    month = checkDate.substr(0,2);
    day = checkDate.substr(3,2);

    var d = new Date("20"+year, month, day);

    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var n = weekday[d.getDay("20"+year, month, day)];
    //RESULT: Sat Apr 18 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

When I put in 03/18/15.. some reason it returns April. 
If I put in 04/14/15, it returns May. 
Its always a month ahead of time. Why is that? Something off in my code?

Comment: What do you mean minimum?

Comment: I mean that when you select tags for your questions, the *very first tag* tag you add should be for the language you're using. **The minimum tags should include a tag for the language**; you can then add additional tags you think are relevant.

Comment: Sorry, don't know why that slipped my mind. Its in javascript. I edited it.

Comment: Everything after the (commented out) `console.log` seems not relevant to your question. Please make sure you provide the actual code that actually shows the result -- nothng more. Even your title focuses on the wrong thing.

Comment: @Jongware I edited the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Months in JavaScript are zero-based. So January is 0, February is 1, ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

An easy fix would be to just subtract one from the month value you get.

Comment: I guess I'll just do that. Thank you.